# Nuxt2/Vue2, checking a $slots sometime fails on rerender

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I have a strange issue on a Nuxt2/Vue2 project.
I have a component with a slot named "image" conditionally displayed. The condition only checks "$slots.image". It works properly on the first render of the component, but if it have to rerender, sometimes the condition fail.

I fixed this issue by modifying the condition to checks also "$scopedSlots.image". But I don't understand what is happening.
Does someone can explain to me what is happening here ?

Here is the parent where my component is imported:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <nav-pane>
      <template #subheader>
        <nav-pane-sub-header>
          <template #image>
            <avatar />
          </template>
        </nav-pane-sub-header>
      </template>
     </nav-pane>
  </div>
</template>
```

Here is my component 'NavPaneSubHeader' with the buggy condition:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <i v-if="icon" />
      <slot v-else-if="$slots.image"/>
    </div>
    <slot />
  </div>
</template>
```

Works fine with :

```html
<slot v-else-if="$scopedSlots.image || $slots.image" />
```

Comment: Define `sometimes` here. Also, what do you mean by `rerender`? Classic reactivity or some page refresh? Do you use scopedSlots somewhere?

Comment: I haven't identified yet what are the differences between when the component properly render and when this issue happen. This I'm not able to define "sometimes" more precisely.

And by rerender, I'm referring to the rendering triggered by Vue's reactivity system.

Comment: There are scopedSlots elsewhere in the app, but they are neither related to my component nor his parent.

Comment: Might be related with: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/12223 , bugged me some time ago. Try two `v-if`s, let me know if it helped.